# How to load javascript module in epub xhtml

Tags: xhtml, epub, epub3, calibre

I have an ebook (ebook1.epub) that loads a javascript file (script1.js) like so:

```
cat EPUB/xhtml/raw/ch1.xhtml
<!--?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?-->
<!DOCTYPE html><html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/script1.js"></script>
...
    </head>
...
</html>

# --------------------------------------------------------------

cat EPUB/package.opf
...
<item id="js4" href="js/script1.js" media-type="text/javascript"/>
```

This works ok. I view the book with:

```
calibre ebook1.epub
```

script1 works as expected, (e.g. calling console.log("foo1") from within script1 responds as expected and prints to the terminal where calibre was launched).

---

Now, I need to use Javascript module file (ES6) (script2.js)
The javascript module file is loaded like so:

```
cat EPUB/xhtml/raw/ch1.xhtml
<!--?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?-->
<!DOCTYPE html><html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <head>
        <script type="module" src="../../js/script2.js"></script>
...
    </head>
...
</html>

# --------------------------------------------------------------

cat EPUB/package.opf
...
<item id="js4" href="js/script2.js" media-type="text/javascript"/>
```

When I ran calibre with

```
calibre ebook2.epub
```

script2 does not work.
Calling function from script2:

- does not print anything to the terminal.
- the terminal shows an error message:

```
ERROR: clbr://internal.sandbox/book/EPUB/js/script2.js:0: Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

How can I load a javascript **module** file in the .epub?

Thanks,
Avner

Answer (score 1):

I installed the latest Calibre version (5.22.1) from [here](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux).
After install, I was able to load module javascript files, and see messages from console.log() in the terminal where I launched Calibre from.

```
cat EPUB/xhtml/raw/ch1.xhtml
<!--?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?-->
<!DOCTYPE html><html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <head>
        <script type="module" src="../../js/script2.js"></script>
...
    </head>
...
</html>

# --------------------------------------------------------------

cat EPUB/package.opf
...
        <item id="js4" href="js/script2.js" media-type="module"/>
```

When I ran calibre with `calibre ebook2.epub` script2.js works ok:
I can see messages from Console.log() in the terminal.

The solution came from [this post](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=4133950#post4133950).